# How to put Label on Column of chart as shown in image

Tags: c#, charts

I want put perfect percentage on each chart column as shown in fig in C# Windows Forms.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYDGa.png]

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Sak's answer which uses the more powerful formatting, you can get a simple percentage by the [Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456687.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) the Chart control provides:

```
yourSeries.Label = "#PERCENT";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, try it:

```
private void fillChart()
{
    //AddXY value in chart1 in series named as Salary  
    chart1.Series["Salary"].Points.AddXY("Ajay", "10000");
    chart1.Series["Salary"].Points.AddXY("Ramesh", "8000");
    chart1.Series["Salary"].Points.AddXY("Ankit", "7000");
    chart1.Series["Salary"].Points.AddXY("Gurmeet", "10000");
    chart1.Series["Salary"].Points.AddXY("Suresh", "8500");
    //chart title  
    chart1.Titles.Add("Salary Chart"); 

    //These lines will show percentages.
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{#}%"; 
    chart1.Series["Salary"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
    chart1.Series["Salary"].LabelFormat = "{#}%"; 
}
```